# Consulta MySql que devuelva valores Cero

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Les comento el problema.
Tengo la suguiente tabla:

[image: Tabla Historicos]

En donde se registran las ventas realizadas, sumarizadas por codigo de producto (campo codigo) en cada una de las sucursales.

Sobre esa tabla realizo la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT 
codigo , sucursal, depto, proveedor,rubro, subrubro, sum(cantidad) as cantidadT, 
sum(cantidad*precio) as Plata 
FROM `historicos` 
WHERE 
`fecha` BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-01' 
GROUP BY codigo, sucursal 
ORDER BY sucursal ASC, codigo ASC, depto ASC
```

Esto me trae los datos que necesito, sumando cantidades y calculando el precio del producto, agrupando por codigo y sucursal.
Esto me devuelve (entre tantos otros resultados):
[image: Resultado]

Pero, como podran ver, tengo codigos que hay sucursales que NO vendieron y no me aparecen en la consulta, por ejemplo el codigo 999449 se vendio en las sucursales 9, 11, 15, 21 y 23, pero yo necesito que si en alguna sucursal NO se vendo, me muestre el registro con codigo, sucursal y el resto de los valores en CERO.
Les comento que la tabla HISTORICOS contiene alrededor de 30 millones de registros.

¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo?
Probe con JOIN LEFT pero no llegue a ningun resultado satisfactorio.

Agradecere cualquier aporte.

Saludos !

Agregado: La tabla de sucursales es la siguiente:

[image: Sucursales]

sucursales.id_sucursal == historicos.sucursal

Gracias !

Comment: Tendrías que incluir en la consulta la tabla de sucursales para pintarlas TODAS, pues en historicos ya viste que, si no se vendió, el registro no existe y no hay cómo incluir esas sucursales. Edita la pregunta e incluye información sobre si tienes una tabla con esa lista. Lo otro, no se entiende por qué usas `fecha BETWEEN 2020-08-01 and 2020-08-01`

Comment: Tengo una tabla con las sucursales... y ese BETWEEN lo uso para limitar un rango de fechas, en este ejemplo lo hice en ese rando (un solo dia) para haces mas liviana la consulta. Ahora edito la pregunta y pongo la estructura de la tabla de sucursales. Gracias!